# Put a default value while indexing time for apache solr

Tags: solr

I am using these code for indexing centerLatitude and centerLongitude, some of the regionID
doesnt have centerLatitude and centerLongitude, it assigns nothing, but want assign 0, 0 for
centerLatitude and centerLongitude if regionID doesnt have it

```
select <entity name="PropertyRegionID"
            query="SELECT IFNULL(r.RegionID, 0) as RegionID from ParentRegionList as r">
            <field column="RegionID" name="RegionID" />

            <entity name="PropertyRegionCenterCoordinates"
                query="SELECT IFNULL(cnt.centerLatitude, 0) as centerLatitude, IFNULL(cnt.centerLongitude, 0) as centerLongitude from RegionCenterCoordinatesList as cnt WHERE cnt.RegionID=${PropertyRegionID.RegionID}">
                <field column="centerLatitude" name="centerLatitude" />
                <field column="centerLongitude" name="centerLongitude" />
           </entity>

       </entity>
```

Any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default="0" in your field definitions:

```
<field column="centerLatitude" name="centerLatitude" default="0"/>
<field column="centerLongitude" name="centerLongitude" default="0"/>
```